# How to add more models to compositeview in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have 3 Backbone.Model instances. I want to add these 3 models to 1 Marionette.CopositeView.

I tried in the following way but it's not working.

```
plannerTableView({el:$('#plannerTablePlace'),model:(modelInstamce1,modelInstance2,modelInstance3)});
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Are the 3 models instances of the same type? Part of the same collection? Then you should add them to a collection and then pass it to the composite view.

Answer (score 0):

CompositeView is for collection, not for models.

To add models, assign the collection to CompositeView instance at first, then add models into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

As Billy Chan said, you should be using a CollectionView (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) to display multiple models of the same type.

There's a step-by-step guide on how to display a collection in the free preview to my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction), take a look: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf